# Never ending batch in PyTorch

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, voice-recognition

In short: training using the mutual information with a positive pair (two samples of same person) and one negative pair. Dont think the "how" is important here.

I need pointers on how to get out of the batching here. should be Epoch -> 10 batch ->epoch but it goes on infinitely. There are a few issues but the main one is that the output is like this:

```
Epoch 1/90:
Batch 1/10
Loss mean:  tensor(nan, grad_fn=<MeanBackward0>)
Batch 2/10
...
Batch 291/10
Loss mean:  tensor(-4.44432, grad_fn=<MeanBackward0>)
```

I do realize the loss is shot but I think I first need to take care of this.

Main train loop:

```
 model.train()
    for epoch in range(args.start_epoch, args.start_epoch + args.epochs):
        print("Epoch {}/{}:".format(epoch + 1, args.start_epoch + args.epochs))
        for i, (batch, speakers) in enumerate(train_loader):
            print("Batch {}/{}   ".format(i + 1, BATCHES_PER_EPOCH))
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            score_posp, score_negp, speakers_probs, speakers = model(torch.tensor(batch, device=device), torch.tensor(speakers, dtype=torch.long, device=device))
            loss = loss_fn(score_negp, score_posp, speakers, speakers_probs)
            print("Loss mean: ", loss.mean())
            loss.mean().backward()
            optimizer.step()
        save_checkpoint({
            'epoch': epoch + 1,
            'state_dict': model.state_dict(),
            'optimizer': optimizer.state_dict(),
        }, filename="./checkpoints/checkpoint_e{}.pth.tar".format(epoch))
    scheduler.step()
```

batching:

```
def make_batch(items):
    samples = [item[0] for item in items]
    speakers = [item[1] for item in items]
    return np.array(samples), np.array(speakers)


    voices_loader = Loader(args.data)

    train_loader = DataLoader(dataset=voices_loader,
                              shuffle=True,
                              num_workers=2,
                              batch_size=BATCHES_PER_EPOCH,
                              collate_fn=make_batch)
```

VoxCelebLoader loads triples with a pair of the same speaker fragments and one random not the same speaker. Can someone help me see why is it infinite?

Comment: How do you compute `BATCHES_PER_EPOCH`?

Comment: @aretor it's a const. here for the sake of the example it's 10 but can be 1000.

Answer (score 0):

its probably just a really long dataset, you can check it by:

```
print(len(voices_loader))
```

it cant be physically infinite if you didn't mess in that
`Loader`
of yours.
if you want to trim it you can use

```
for epoch in range(args.start_epoch, args.start_epoch + args.epochs):
    print("Epoch {}/{}:".format(epoch + 1, args.start_epoch + args.epochs))
    for i, (batch, speakers) in enumerate(train_loader):
        if i >= 1000:
            break
        *your code*
```

Comment: Thank you! the size is 12800, so that might explain it. Is trimming it like this ok or is there another way?

Comment: well if you're in a hurry you can trim it, it's okay if you want to train your model fast, but there's no sense. It's even worse if you didnt shuffle your dataloader (by adding param shuffle=True), so I just recommend to let it be